# Passing Context from the main Activity to another class

Tags: android, android-context

This might be the wrong way to go about this, so tell me if that's the case:

I'm trying to use getFileStreamPath (which is derived from Context, as far as I understand) in another class, to separate some code from the main activity class. I'm doing this by passing the main activity's context to the other class, and using that to invoke its methods.

In my main activity class:

```
LocalStorage lc = new LocalStorage(this);
```

Then, in the other class:

```
public class LocalStorage {
    Context ctx;

    public LocalStorage (Context c) {
        c = ctx;
        File lfile = ctx.getFileStreamPath("Activity.log");

    ....
```

But obviously I'm missing something, because running getFileStreamPath on the passed context in the LocalStorage class results in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have your variables backwards.

```
c = ctx;
```

should be

```
ctx = c;
```

You're assigning the uninitialized `Context` `ctx` to the passed in `Context` `c`, so it will always be null.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you made a typo ?

```
public LocalStorage (Context c) {
    ctx = c;
    ...
```

Comment: Oh my god...embarassing. It's apparently possible to get blind while looking at your own code. Yes, it was the topy :-)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It happens all the time for me ^^

Answer (score 1):

c = ctx ???

```
Context ctx;

public LocalStorage (Context c) {
    c = ctx;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is the bug in your code, we miss information. But looks like you're passing the context in the right way. So the problem is away.